# UL inside LI being pushed sideways

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm making use of `ul`'s inside of `li` tags

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>..</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my question is, how can I avoid the inner `ul` finding itself automatically rendered slightly pushed to the right hand side (what would seem to a be a default accordeon "styling")? without playing around with negative margins.

Comment: Use `ul ul{padding-left: 0;}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Further @Vucko comment

```css
ul ul {
  padding-left:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      Text
        <ul>
            <li>..</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```